# vim path expand stuck in 8.3 mode

Tags: vim

Running vim 7.3 on win32.

```
:echo expand("%:p")  
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft\ Shared\Stationery\Bears.htm
```

That's fine.

```
:echo expand("%:p:8")  
C:\PROGRA~1\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\STATIO~1\Bears.htm
```

And that's fine.

But try the original expand again, and vim still gives me the 8.3 path:

```
:echo expand("%:p")  
C:\PROGRA~1\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\STATIO~1\Bears.htm
```

How can I get out of that 8.3 mode?

Comment: Seems like a bug in vim!  First I've seen...

Comment: Thanks.  I've sent a bug report to vim.org.

Comment: Wow, Bram replied to me the next day, and fixed it!  7.3.281 has the patch.

Comment: I'm not surprised, Bram rocks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug that was fixed in vim version 7.3.281